# Epson Stylus CX5600: Can't print

Tags: printing, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint 11 (Katya). My printer is perfeclty recognized by the OS and I can configure it without problems.

But when I try to print anything, both the printer's power led and error led start blinking, and nothing happens. The printer worked just fine in previous versions of Ubuntu. I suspect that ink might be low, but there is no way to check because the ubuntu driver doesn't have that functionality. Plus, I don't have a Windows box available.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For testing purpose to see if printer is working correctly under Windows you could use Sun's VirtualBox.

Comment: That's it! It had ran out of ink (checked in Windows virtual machine with drivers installed). Replaced cartridges, and now it works fine in Mint. Post your comment as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Nice! You found an answer yourself, why not just answer your own question and get this question to green, answered side :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had ran out of ink. I created a Windows XP virtual machine using Virtual Box, installed the drivers there and the ink-level utility told me I was out of black. So I refilled, and voila! I could print in Mint again.

It's bothersome having to go to the virtual Windows machine periodically to check ink levels, but it works. Mind it, I tried some Linux ink level checking utilities I found on the web, but failed miserably with all of them. Seems the CX5600 is too old...